# Modeling three-way relationship in SQL/Django ORM

Tags: django

Can anyone help me figure out how to model the following relationship in Django's ORM?

I have a set of people. These people may belong to zero or more organizations. For each organization a person belongs to, that person has a title within that organization.

For example, John is a member of both ACME Corp and EVIL Inc. Within ACME Corp, he is the VP of Sales, while within EVIL Inc, he is the CEO.

I know this sounds unrealistic, but this application is for a non-profit in an industry where many people belong to several different organizations/funding bodies/committees, etc.

I've got the person -> organization part working (easy enough, as its just a ManyToManyField), but I have no clue how to implement specific titles for each row the foreign key points to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a custom `through` model to save extra data for a single relationship:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    organisations = models.ManyToManyField(Organisation, through='Position')

class Position(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    organisation = models.ForeignKey(Organisation)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Also check the documentation on [`through` models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through).

Comment: Awesome! I had never heard of those before. Thanks :)